# Windows application enable parent form button from child form button click

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, wizard, wizard-control

I'm trying to create my own Next/back wizard control using multiple forms,
In that I'm facing a problem in one scenario. 
I have my next/back button in parent form, default the next button will be enabled false after few validation in child form. I'm trying to enable parent Next button.
I can't seem able to make it happen. I have tried the code shown below.

I'm trying this below code from my child form:

Default My parent form
Step1 my child form

Step1:

```
1.
Default d = new Default();
d.btnNext.Enabled = true;

2.
(this.Owner as Default).btnNext.Enabled = true;

3.
Default p = (Default)this.Owner;
Control[] c = p.Controls.Find("btnNext", true);
Button b = (Button)c[0];
b.Enabled = false;
```

[image]

Comment: i trying this below code from my child form Step1: </n>

Default d = new Default();</n>
d.btnNext.Enabled = true;</n>
-------
(this.Owner as Default).btnNext.Enabled = true;</n>
-------
Default p = (Default)this.Owner;</n>
Control[] c = p.Controls.Find("btnNext", true);</n>
Button b = (Button)c[0];</n>
b.Enabled = false;</n>

Comment: can you edit your question and put the code in there ? It is to unreadable here in the comments and it is information that anyone that reads the question should know without having to read comments